# How to get mail from UID for pop3 protocol

Tags: jakarta-mail, pop3

I am using javaMail Api to read the mail attachments using pop3 protocol. Please tell me is there any way to get mail from UID (unique id) for pop3 protocol, same as imap protocol where we have methods to get mail from UID.

Comment: Please show your codes.

Answer (score 2):

See the [javadocs for the com.sun.mail.pop3 package](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html) to get started.  The UID support in the POP3 protocol is very primitive compared to what IMAP supports.  You can't directly get a message based on a UID, but you can get a list of all the UIDs for all the messages and look through the list yourself to find out which message has the UID you're looking for.